# How do I use GObject in Eclipse? (Java)

Tags: java, package, syntax-error

I'm testing a program I found in Eclipse. One of the class declarations includes

'''public class Title extends GObject'''

Here I'm getting the error "GObject cannot be resolved to a type"

I also get errors when GStyle, GSegment, GPosition, GText are used as a result of the error with GObject. I'm trying to make a GUI that works with these things

Full code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import no.geosoft.cc.graphics.*;
import java.awt.*;

class TOH_solver_demo extends JFrame{
    private Peg[] bolt;
    private JButton s_button;
    private GWindow my_wndw;
    private T_of_Hanoi TOH_;
    private int num_disk;

    public TOH_solver_demo(int n_disk){
        super();
        num_disk = n_disk;
        // to exit the JFrame on closing
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Creating a canvas from GWindow class
        my_wndw = new GWindow(new Color(190, 220, 190));
        // adding the canvas
        getContentPane().add(my_wndw.getCanvas());
        // Create an object of GScene class
        GScene scene = new GScene (my_wndw);
        double w_1[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
        double w_2[] = {4.0, 0.0, 0.0};
        double w_3[] = {0.0, num_disk*2, 0.0};
        scene.setWorldExtent(w_1, w_2, w_3);
        // creating an object of Title class and adding
        // it to the scene
        scene.add(new Title());
        // Using a for loop to iteratively
        // create pegs(3 here) and adding it to the scene
        int nPegs = 3;
        bolt = new Peg[nPegs];
        for(int j=0; j<nPegs; j++) {
            bolt[j] = new Peg(j+1.0);
            scene.add(bolt[j]);
        }
        // Using a for loop to iteratively add the number of disks
        // provided by the user to the first peg and
        // futher adding it to the scene
        for(int j=0; j<n_disk; j++) {
            Custom_Disk my_disk = new 
                        Custom_Disk((double)(n_disk-j)/n_disk);
            my_disk.set_disk_pos(1.0, j);
            bolt[0].add(my_disk);
        }
        // packing everything
        pack();
        // setting the size of the canvas into
        // dimension of 600, 600
        setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        // setting the visibility of the canvas to 'true' so
        // that it can be seen
        setVisible(true);
        // Create an object of TowersOfHanoi class
        TOH_ = new T_of_Hanoi();
        // calling the instance method solve to
        // solve the Towers of Hanoi and display it
        TOH_.solve();
    }
    public void disk_mover(int src_bolt, int dest_bolt)
    {
        // Creating an object of Custom_Disk class to move the disc
        Custom_Disk my_disk = 
(Custom_Disk)bolt[src_bolt].getChild(bolt[src_bolt].getNChildren()-1);
        // variables to store the horizontal position of bolt
        // according to the disk
        double hor_0 = bolt[src_bolt].x_getter();
        double hor_1 = bolt[dest_bolt].x_getter();
        // variables to store the vertical position of disk in bolt
        double vert_0 = my_disk.get_disk_y();
        double vert_1 = num_disk+4.0;
        // Animatation step of vertical movement of disk
        double my_step = 0.2;
        double y_pos = vert_0;
        while(y_pos < vert_1) {
            my_disk.set_disk_pos(hor_0, y_pos);
            my_disk.redraw();
            my_wndw.refresh();
            y_pos += my_step;
        }
        bolt[src_bolt].remove(my_disk);
        bolt[dest_bolt].add(my_disk);
        // Animatation step of horizontal movement of disk
        my_step = 0.05;
        double x_pos = hor_0;
        while(x_pos != hor_1){
            my_disk.set_disk_pos(x_pos, y_pos);
            my_disk.redraw();
            my_wndw.refresh();
            x_pos += (hor_1 > hor_0 ? my_step : -my_step);
            if (Math.abs(x_pos - hor_1) < 0.01)
                x_pos = hor_1;
        }
        // Animatation step of vertical movement of disk
        my_step = 0.2;
        y_pos  = vert_1;
        vert_1 = bolt[dest_bolt].getNChildren()-1;
        while(y_pos > vert_1){
            if (Math.abs (y_pos - vert_1) < 0.01)
                y_pos = vert_1;
            my_disk.set_disk_pos(x_pos, y_pos);
            my_disk.redraw();
            my_wndw.refresh();
            y_pos -= my_step;
        }
    }
  
    // To create Title in the canvas
    class Title extends GObject{
        // variable to store an object of GSegment 
        private GSegment custom_anchor;
        // constructor of Title class
        public Title(){
            // create an object GStyle class
            GStyle custom_style = new GStyle();
            // setting the foreground color
            custom_style.setForegroundColor(new Color(80, 100, 200));
            custom_style.setLineStyle(GStyle.LINESTYLE_INVISIBLE);
            // setting the font to serif with a size of 24
            custom_style.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            setStyle(custom_style);
            // instantiating a GSegment class object
            custom_anchor = new GSegment();
            addSegment(custom_anchor);
            // Creating an object of Gtext class to
            // display "towers of hanoi solver"
            GText text = new GText("TOH SOLVER", GPosition.SOUTHWEST);
            // setting the GText object to the GSegment object
            custom_anchor.setText(text);
        }
        public void draw(){
            custom_anchor.setGeometry(20, 20);
        }
    }
    // Peg class to display the peg as a graphics
    class Peg extends GObject{
        private double[] peg_xy;
        private GSegment curr_peg;
        private double my_peg_pos;
        public Peg(double x)
        {
            my_peg_pos = x;
            // creating an object of GStyle class
            GStyle custom_style = new GStyle();
            // setting the background color of peg
            custom_style.setBackgroundColor(new Color (100, 100, 100));
            setStyle(custom_style);
            // creatinf an object of GSegment for the peg
            curr_peg = new GSegment();
            addSegment(curr_peg);
            // position of peg
            peg_xy = new double[] {my_peg_pos - 0.05, 0.0,
                                    my_peg_pos - 0.05, num_disk + 2,
                                    my_peg_pos + 0.05, num_disk + 2,
                                    my_peg_pos + 0.05, 0.0,
                                    my_peg_pos - 0.05, 0.0};
        }
        public void draw(){
            curr_peg.setGeometryXy(peg_xy);
        }
        public double x_getter(){
            return my_peg_pos;
        }
    }

    class Custom_Disk extends GObject{
        private double disk_size;
        private GSegment curr_disk;
        private double disk_x, disk_y;
    
        public Custom_Disk (double size)
        {
            disk_size = size;
            // creating an object of GStyle class for styling of disk
            GStyle custom_style = new GStyle();
            // setting the background color of disk
            custom_style.setBackgroundColor(new Color(255, 150, 150));
            // setting the forecolor of disk
            custom_style.setForegroundColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
            setStyle(custom_style);
            // instantiating curr_disk Gsegment object
            curr_disk = new GSegment();
            addSegment(curr_disk);
        }
        public double get_disk_y(){
            return disk_y;
        }
        public void set_disk_pos(double x_pos, double y_pos){
            disk_x = x_pos;
            disk_y = y_pos;
        }
        public void draw(){
            double[] pos_xy = new 
                      double[]{disk_x - disk_size / 2.0, disk_y,
                      disk_x - disk_size / 2.0, disk_y + 1.0,
                      disk_x + disk_size / 2.0, disk_y + 1.0,
                      disk_x + disk_size / 2.0, disk_y,
                      disk_x - disk_size / 2.0, disk_y};
        curr_disk.setGeometryXy(pos_xy);
        }
    }
    // class to solve the Tower of Hanoi problem
    class T_of_Hanoi{
        public void solve(){
            solve(num_disk, 0, 2, 1);    
        }
        // solve the problem recursively
        private void solve(int n_disk, int src_bolt, int dest_bolt, int auxiliary){
            if(n_disk==1)
                disk_mover(src_bolt, dest_bolt);
            else if(n_disk>1) {
                solve(n_disk - 1, src_bolt, auxiliary, dest_bolt);
                disk_mover(src_bolt, dest_bolt);
                solve(n_disk-1, auxiliary, dest_bolt, src_bolt);
            }
        }
    }  
}
class Prog467_8_11{
    // driver method
    public static void main (String[] args){
        // Scanner class object to take user input for number of disks
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Display to ask the user for the number of disks
        System.out.println("Enter the number of disks");
        int user_num_disk = sc.nextInt();
        TOH_solver_demo demo = new TOH_solver_demo(user_num_disk);
    } 
}
```

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS `GObject` is imported by `import no.geosoft.cc.graphics.*;`, from [this library](https://geosoft.no/graphics/) but yeah, forcing us to look it up instead of mentioning it in the question doesn't help.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Now I just have to figure out how to import the jar file so I can use it